Role of would in sentence
What is the role of "would"? I often see a native speaker using it when replying to a question.

I would understand that to be...
I would take it to mean...
I would interpret that as...
I would estimate...

And each of these can also be said without the word "would."

I understand that to be...
I take it to mean...
I interpret that as...
I estimate...

I think adding in the word "would" and don't are the same, that is, the speaker emphasises that this is an interpretation or opinion. Other might disagree with me. My confusion is why the speaker adds "would"?

The Cambridge Dictionary offers several meanings of would, one of which is

used to express an opinion in a polite way without being forceful

I would suggest that this is the intended meaning in your sentences.

Politeness is one practical meaning of the lack of "forcefulness" expressed by the modal. Another is a hint of tentativeness. Given my (possibly incomplete) knowledge of the context, I tend to think ...

"Tentantiveness" in this context refers to conditional, doesn't it?

It's not as though there is an ellipted conditional phrase, but there is a tacit condition that keeps the speaker from making the assertion without the modal's reservation. That reserve is often taken for politeness and it often is politeness but it need not be politeness. One might have other reasons to express something in a reserved manner.
